# Storing Encrypted Voucher Codes in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, encryption, field-level-security, field-level-encryption

We are using a lot of vouchers in our marketing campaigns and usually, vouchers are uniquely assigned to a specific user when they are being issued on the back-end, and therefore no other user can redeem those.

Right now I am planning to run a number of reactivation campaigns where we are planning to issue vouchers in bulk, store them in one of the DEs and assign them using AMPscript.

This has raised a lot of ethical issues, as there is a bunch of people who have access to the platform and technically vouchers are "free and unassigned" just gonna be sitting there...and you know...tempting :)

I am currently exploring an option of storing vouchers in a field-level encrypted format.
The objective is ultimately to keep the voucher codes hidden from the platform users and only display them as personalization field to recipients and team members with the specific access level.

Has anyone attempted and succeeded in achieving this and can share their experience?

Any solutions are highly appreciated :)

Comment: Another thing you should keep in mind when you want to encrypt is the decryption. Normally this decryption would either be done on a website or inside the ampscript logic of the email. Therefore when somebody is previewing emails that will be send they might even see the decrypted voucher code again (depends on implementation) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of, is using [Field Level Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_field_level_encryption.htm&type=5) which would encrypt the vouchers during import and decrypt them at send-time. They will be stored in a data extension in an encrypted format, preventing them from being viewed by people with platform access.

However, it is a LOT of work (and an additional license with a $$ price tag) to guard yourself from a relatively small risk. So far I haven't seen this used solely for the purpose of preventing voucher codes from being viewed.

You could consider [DecryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DecryptSymmetric.htm) in your emails, if you are able to apply same encryption algorithm on your vouchers prior to importing them. However, as Johannes also states, this will present the voucher in plain text when doing Preview and Test in Content Builder.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas I agree that the risk is low, but thought its good to explore the options so that i have a back-up :)

Comment: You are welcome, @Kat - remember to mark the answer as accepted, and upvote if you found it helpful